# PDF4NET Creating Pages and Adjusting Size/Orientation

Tags: c#, pdf

I recently upgraded my application pdf4net version to version 13.2.1 and encountered some changes in the API. Previously, I used the following code to create a page in pdf and draw an image into it:

```
System.Drawing.Image objImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imgPath);
PDFPage page = pdfDoc.AddPage();        
page.Size = PDFPageSize.A4;
page.Orientation = PDFPageOrientation.Landscape;
page.Canvas.DrawImage(decodedPath, 0, 0, objImage.Width, objImage.Height, 0, PDFKeepAspectRatio.KeepBoth);
```

I'm uncertain about the correct approach. Currently, I'm using the following code:

```
PDFImage objImage = new PDFImage(imgPath);
PDFFixedDocument pdfDoc = new PDFFixedDocument();
PDFPage page = pdfDoc.Pages.Add();
page.Width = objImage.Width;
page.Height = objImage.Height;
page.Canvas.DrawImage(objImage, 0, 0, objImage.Width, objImage.Height);
```

My questions are:

1. Is this the correct way of create a page in pdf?
2. How can I set the page size and orientation?

I appreciate any insights or examples on how to achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is the equivalent of the old code:

```
PDFImage objImage = new PDFImage(imgPath);
PDFFixedDocument pdfDoc = new PDFFixedDocument();
PDFPage page = pdfDoc.Pages.Add();
page.Width = 842;
page.Height = 595;
page.Canvas.DrawImage(objImage, 0, 0, -objImage.Width, -objImage.Height);
```

The negative image dimensions means to draw the image in the specified rectangle and keep the original image aspect ratio.

You can create a landscape A4 page in 2 ways:

1.

```
PDFPage page = pdfDoc.Pages.Add();
page.Width = 842;
page.Height = 595;
```

or

2.

```
PDFPage page = pdfDoc.Pages.Add();
page.Width = 595;
page.Height = 842;
page.Rotation = 90;
```

Note: I work for the company that develops [PDF4NET](https://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm).